# Sqoop giving following Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue , Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow

Tags: sqoop

While trying to import a table from RDBMS Sqoop is erroring out with following error log:

```
>Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
>        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:277)
>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
>        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
>        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
>Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
>        at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4170)
>        at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getBigDecimal(NumberCommonAccessor.java:2376)
>        at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getBigDecimal(GeneratedStatement.java:96)
>        at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getBigDecimal(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:126)
>        at org.apache.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readBigDecimal(JdbcWritableBridge.java:126)
>        at com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readBigDecimal(JdbcWritableBridge.java:97)
>        at QueryResult.readFields(QueryResult.java:3639)
>        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:244)
>        ... 12 more
>Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
>Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
>Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

Though error is understandable & it seems that some column value is having a value which can not fit into one of data type decided by sqoop, but issue is there are 180 odd columns & millions of records then how to identify which column is creating this trouble.
How to debug & fix this?

Comment: Can you  please share your Sqoop command ?

Comment: sqoop import -D mapred.child.java.opts="\-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom" --direct --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@abcd.com.gh:1521/aaa -username abc -password xxx --verbose --as-textfile -m 1 --query "select * from schema.table_name where datekey = 20170829 and subpart = 3 and rownum<=100000" --target-dir /path/to/hdfs/dir --fields-terminated-by '\b' --null-string "" --null-non-string "" --hive-delims-replacement ' '